# Ghost on docker : curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Tags: docker, ghost-blog

I managed to set up ghost blog on my raspberry pi.I was able to access the index page on curl without issues. But I had to restart my container. After restarting the container, I cannot access the site anymore.

I get the following error when I run the command

```
curl http://localhost:4500
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

If I spin up a new container it works fine. How can I rectify the above error?

I managed to isolate the issue. It's seems to be an issue with ip binding but am unsure how to reolve it.
[Docker Rails app fails to be served - curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27806631/docker-rails-app-fails-to-be-served-curl-56-recv-failure-connection-reset)

As suggested in the above question, I tried curl inside the container  and it works. I also tried from the host using the container ip and that works as well. It fails when i curl usint localhost:portnumber.

Comment: which image are you using? the official one?