# How can I get my dockerized Python app to output on 2 separate ports?

Tags: docker, curl, port

I have a dockerized Python app that outputs data on port 8080 and port 8081.
I am running the code on a Ubuntu system.

```
$ docker version | grep Version
 Version:      18.03.1-ce
```

The app responds on port 8080

```
$ curl -k localhost:8080 | tail -4
-->
TYPE hello_world_total counter
hello_world_total 3.0
TYPE hello_world_created gauge
hello_world_created 1.5617357381235116e+09
```

The app returns an ERROR on port 8081

```
$ curl -k localhost:8081
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Although I am not familiar with netstat, I used it to check that ports 8080 and 8081 were both in the LISTEN state ...

```
root@1d1ac2974893:/# netstat -apn
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/python3
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8081          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/python3
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.2:58220        16.46.41.11:8080        TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.2:58218        16.46.41.11:8080        TIME_WAIT   -
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name     Path
root@1d1ac2974893:/#
```

My Dockerfile looks as follows ...

```
$ cat Dockerfile
FROM python:3
RUN pip3 install prometheus_client
COPY sampleapp.py /src/sampleapp.py
EXPOSE 8081
CMD [ "python3", "/src/sampleapp.py" ]
```

When I run the application, I map both ports 8080 and 8081 from the Docker container to the same ports on the host as follows ...

```
$ docker run -p 8081:8081 -p 8080:8080 sampleapp
```

If I go into the Container and repeat the above curl commands, they work as I expect.

```
root@1d1ac2974893:/# curl -k localhost:8081 | tail -4
TYPE hello_world_total counter
hello_world_total 3.0
TYPE hello_world_created gauge
hello_world_created 1.5617357381235116e+09
root@1d1ac2974893:/#
```

AND

```
$ docker exec -it 1d1ac2974893 /bin/bash
root@1d1ac2974893:/# curl -k localhost:8081
Hello World
```

SO
the question is why the latter curl command does NOT work from the host system.

```
$ curl -k localhost:8081
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution was as follows

1. Expose both ports in the Dockerfile

   `$ grep EXPOSE Dockerfile
   EXPOSE 8080
   EXPOSE 8081`
2. Use 0.0.0.0 rather than 127.0.0.1

   `import http.server
   from prometheus_client import start_http_server
   from prometheus_client import Counter`

   HOST='0.0.0.0'
   HELLO_WORLD_PORT=8080
   HELLO_WORLD_METRICS_PORT=8081
   REQUESTS = Counter('hello_world_total', 'Hello World Requested')

   class MyHandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
       def do_GET(self):
           REQUESTS.inc()
           self.send_response(200)
           self.end_headers()
           self.wfile.write(b"Hello World\n")

   if **name** == "**main**":
       start_http_server(HELLO_WORLD_METRICS_PORT)
       server = http.server.HTTPServer((HOST, HELLO_WORLD_PORT), MyHandler)
       server.serve_forever()

Contaainer now gives the expected results when run from the host

    `$ curl -k localhost:8080
    Hello World
    $ 
    $ curl -k localhost:8081 | tail -4
    ...
    # TYPE hello_world_total counter
    hello_world_total 1.0
    # TYPE hello_world_created gauge
    hello_world_created 1.5619773258069074e+09
    $`

Xref :- [Docker Rails app fails to be served - curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27806631/docker-rails-app-fails-to-be-served-curl-56-recv-failure-connection-reset)
for details of a similar issue